# Check the render method of `TabBarIcon`

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I wanna add icons in the bottom Tab Navigation and facing the above error.
if I am using this code without icons then everything is fine I mean Tab Bar work properly.

complete error is:
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `TabBarIcon`.

My Code is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text,} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer, StackActions} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {Ionicons} from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import Category from './Pages/Category';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
export default function App(){
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={ props=> ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
          let iconName;
          if(props.route.name === "Home"){
            iconName = focused
            ? "ios-information-circle"
            : "ios-information-circle-outline";
          }
          if(props.route.name === "Category"){
            iconName = focused
            ? "ios-information-circle"
            : "ios-information-circle-outline";
          }
          return <Ionicons name={iconName} color={color} size={size} />;},}) }>
<Tab.Screen 
      name="Home" component={Home}></Tab.Screen>
      <Tab.Screen name="Category" component={Category}></Tab.Screen>
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
)}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your import of Ionicons is wrong
it should be a default import like below

```
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

Basically when you import like you have done it would be undefined and throwing the error.

Comment: can you tell me where I can read the name of icons because I don't know about the icon names

Comment: this page has the list of icons https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/